# Reading snort log pcap file

Tags: python, shell, pcap, snort

**What I am upto?**

1)I am using inotifytools to watch on var/log/snort dir
2) as soon as new log file generated in this dir, I add it to a pipe with a shell script.
3) this shell script gives me newly added line(new packet) to that log file which looks something like this **0600 0108 0006 0400 01c4 6e1f 11b3 99c0**

**What I want?**

How can I create new pcap file with only this packet? **0600 0108 0006 0400 01c4 6e1f 11b3 99c0**

**Why I want it?**
The above created pcap file I will use to give input to **dpkt.pcap.Reader** to get details about that packet

Comment: If you want to put every new line to separate file, you can do like while read LINE; do echo $LINE > file.`date +%Y-%m-$d_%H:%M:%S`

Comment: didn't get your point, Can you please elaborate?